# Is there a way to get an array of this month's calendar data in swift?

Tags: swift

I would like to create a calendar in swift. Is there a built in library for Swift that can return a list of the [dayofweek, day, month, year] data for every day in this current month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use [`Calendar`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar) for this.

For example, you can use [`range(of:in:for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293059-range) to get the range of the days of the current month. And as Leo pointed out, you can then build an array of dates by building a `Date` from the components using the updated day of the month. And then you can use [`dateComponents(_:from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293646-datecomponents) to get the day of the week.

```
let now = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current

guard let dayRange = calendar.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: now) else { return }
var components = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year, .era], from: now)

let componentsForWholeMonth = dayRange.compactMap { day -> DateComponents? in
    components.day = day
    return calendar.date(from: components).flatMap {
        calendar.dateComponents([.weekday, .day, .month, .year], from: $0)
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
for components in componentsForWholeMonth {
    print(components.weekday!, components.day!, components.month!, components.year!)
}
```

Comment: It is 11:45pm here of the last day in the month and your code is returning `4 1 7 2020
5 2 7 2020
6 3 7 2020
7 4 7 2020
1 5 7 2020
2 6 7 2020
3 7 7 2020
4 8 7 2020
5 9 7 2020
6 10 7 2020
7 11 7 2020
1 12 7 2020
2 13 7 2020
3 14 7 2020
4 15 7 2020
5 16 7 2020
6 17 7 2020
7 18 7 2020
1 19 7 2020
2 20 7 2020
3 21 7 2020
4 22 7 2020
5 23 7 2020
6 24 7 2020
7 25 7 2020
1 26 7 2020
2 27 7 2020
3 28 7 2020
4 29 7 2020
3 30 6 2020` the next months dates except the last one https://www.dropbox.com/s/baqpudnxftcvk4k/dates.png?dl=1

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bxpeslpa86m4ejt/dates2.png?dl=1

Comment: you can get the `.calendar` component instead of the `.era` and then `let componentsForWholeMonth = dayRange.map { day -> DateComponents in`
    `components.day = day`
    `return calendar.dateComponents([.weekday, .day, .month, .year], from: components.date!)`
`}`

Comment: Do you really think it is necessary that guard when getting the day range in month? I don't think it can ever fail.

Comment: `DateComponents` has a `date` property. Generally it would return `nil` but if you set the `calendar` property it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216993/discussion-between-rob-and-leo-dabus).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with rob about the usage of calendar's method range(of:in:for:) but you should get also the year and month components from the original date and manually create your dates instead of adding the day component to it:

```
extension Date {
    func year(using calendar: Calendar = .current) -> Int {
        calendar.component(.year, from: self)
    }
    func month(using calendar: Calendar = .current) -> Int {
        calendar.component(.month, from: self)
    }
}
```

---

```
let now = Date()
let year = now.year()
let month = now.month()
let range = Calendar.current.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: now)!
let components = range.map { day -> DateComponents in
    let date = DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: year, month: month, day: day).date!
    return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday, .day, .month, .year], from: date)
}
for element in components {
    print(element.weekday!, element.day!, element.month!, element.year!)
}
```

---

This will print:

```
2 1 6 2020
3 2 6 2020
4 3 6 2020
5 4 6 2020
6 5 6 2020
7 6 6 2020
1 7 6 2020
2 8 6 2020
3 9 6 2020
4 10 6 2020
5 11 6 2020
6 12 6 2020
7 13 6 2020
1 14 6 2020
2 15 6 2020
3 16 6 2020
4 17 6 2020
5 18 6 2020
6 19 6 2020
7 20 6 2020
1 21 6 2020
2 22 6 2020
3 23 6 2020
4 24 6 2020
5 25 6 2020
6 26 6 2020
7 27 6 2020
1 28 6 2020
2 29 6 2020
3 30 6 2020
```